# Extending and implementing ADTs in java with generics

Tags: java, generics

Im trying to make an an implementation of a doublyLinked List. I have a few classes.
A DoubleNode<E extends Comparable> class for each node. A DLL<E extends Comparable> class for the implementation of it's functions and a GenericADTSortedList<E extends Comparable> class all of which I made.

I tested all the functions and they all work great however now Im trying to use that as my data structure for an address book. I created a contact class and an addressbook class that takes in a contact as a parameter in it's constructor and create a GenericADTSortedList but I get

'''Bound mismatch: The type Contact is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable> of the type GenericADTSortedList'''

`public class GenericADTSortedList<E extends Comparable<E>>{`

`public class DLL<E extends Comparable<E>> {`

`public class DoubleNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<E> {`

the "compareTo" Overriddden method is defined in DoubleNode.

GenericADTSortedList has a DoublyLinkedList and contains a bunch of DoubleNode elements.

```
public class Contact{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Contact()
    {
        //blank default constructor
    }

    public Contact(String fName, String lName, String pNum)
    {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.phoneNumber = pNum;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Contact: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + phoneNumber;
    }


}
```

```
    GenericADTSortedList<E> addBook;
    

    public AddressBook()
    {
        //default constructor
    }

    public AddressBook()
    {
        GenericADTSortedList<Contact> book = new GenericADTSortedList<Contact>();
//Error! Bound mismatch: The type Contact is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable> of the type GenericADTSortedList

        
    }
}
```

I've tried seeing if I put implements or extends in different places but I cant seem to understand the class interaction. There's not a lot of very student friendly readable information on how abstract data types and use defined classes work with Generics while implementing comparable.

The AddressBook isn't supposed to be generic so I'm not exactly sure what's wrong? Any help appreciated.

*****SOLVED: This question was solved as I was typing it up. Im leaving it here for other CS students struggling with generics and user defined classes like I was at the time*****

Answer (score 0):

My buddy solved it! Basically what I missed was that the class for Contact needs to implement Comparable to be compatible with the GenericADTSortedList.

So if you keep all the headers from my question the same but all you do is add implements Comparable to the end of the Contact Class definition it solves the issue where it's a bounds mismatch.

So change
`public class Contact{...`
to
`public class Contact __implements Comparable<Contact>__{...`
and Voila! Fixed.